# invalid use of non-static member function

Tags: c++, function, constants, member, non-static

I have something like this:

```
class Bar
      {
      public:
        pair<string,string> one;
        std::vector<string> cars;
        Bar(string one, string two, string car);
      };

class Car
      {
      public:
        string rz;
        Bar* owner;
        Car(string car, Bar* p);
      };

class Foo
       {
         public:
          Foo  ( void );
          ~Foo  ( void );
          int Count ( const string & one, const string &  two) const;
          int comparator (const Bar & first, const Bar & second) const;            
            std::vector<Bar> bars;
       };

int Foo::comparator(const Bar & first, const Bar & second) const{
  return first.name < second.name;
}

int Foo::Count  ( const string & one, const string & two ) const{
  int result=0;
  Bar mybar = Bar( one, two, "" );
  std::vector<Bar>::iterator ToFind = lower_bound(bars.begin(), bars.end(), mybar, comparator);
  if (ToFind != bars.end() && ToFind->one == mybar.one ){
    result = ...
  }
  return result;
}
```

The method `Foo::Count` should use `std::lower_bound()` to find element in `vector<Bar>` according to pair of two strings. 
Now the part which doesn't work. To `lower_bound()` I'm providing method `comparator()`. I thought it was okay, but g++ says:

```
c.cpp: In member function ‘int Foo::Count(const string&, const string&) const’:
c.cpp:42:94: error: invalid use of non-static member function
std::vector<Bar>::iterator ToFind = lower_bound(bars.begin(), bars.end(), mybar, comparator);
```

And the method `Count()` must stay `const`...

I'm quite new to C++ because I'm forced to learn it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why exactly isn't that function static?

Comment: Which one? I am not allowed to change the declaration of the function Count()

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You must make `Foo::comparator` static or wrap it in a `std::mem_fun` class object.  This is because `lower_bounds()` expects the comparer to be a class of object that has a call operator, like a function pointer or a functor object.  Also, if you are using C++11 or later, you can also do as [dwcanillas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1359034/dwcanillas) suggests and use a lambda function.  C++11 also has `std::bind` too.

Examples:

```
// Binding:
std::lower_bounds(first, last, value, std::bind(&Foo::comparitor, this, _1, _2));
// Lambda:
std::lower_bounds(first, last, value, [](const Bar & first, const Bar & second) { return ...; });
```

Comment: You're welcome.  I would make the case that the comparison function be static though since it does not access the class.

Answer (score 34):

The simplest fix is to make the comparator function be static:

```
static int comparator (const Bar & first, const Bar & second);
^^^^^^
```

When invoking it in `Count`, its name will be `Foo::comparator`.

The way you have it now, it does not make sense to be a non-static member function because it does not use any member variables of `Foo`.

Another option is to make it a non-member function, especially if it makes sense that this comparator might be used by other code besides just `Foo`.

Answer (score 7):

You shall pass a `this` pointer to tell the function which object to work on because it relies on that as opposed to a `static` member function.